# Remove a specific nested object from an array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to remove a specific object that is nested inside an array of objects.

The following db structure looks like:

[image: imd]

I would like to remove one of the teams based on the **roomId** (to find the specific room) and based on the team **approved** state. If a team has "approved: false" it needs to be deleted from the array of objects.

I'm using mongoose and came up with the following, but without succes:

```
     Room.update({"roomId": req.params.roomId},
        {"$pull": { "teams.approved": false } })
```

screenshot thats shows the correct roomId: 
[image: img]

Comment: The answers of Nicolas Maties and mickl are correct, it might be `req.params.roomId` giving you a bad value, `console.log(req.params.roomId)` and make sure it has a value

Comment: it does have a value and its the correct roomId, Look at the screenshot above in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array name and equality condition should be specified separately like in [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents) example, try:

```
await Room.update({"roomId": req.params.roomId}, {"$pull": { "teams": { approved: false } } })
```

Comment: I've tried the above, it doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: @Krelis could you check if `req.params.roomId` has expected value and type ?

Comment: it does, see screenshot above in the initial post.

Comment: @Krelis I don't see any callback / await in your code, possibly that can be the problem, could you check that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work:

```
Room.find({roomId: 1234}).then((result) => {
if (result) {
 return Room.remove({result.teams.approved: false})
 } 
} ).catch()
```

You still need to first find all results matching the *roomId* number and then removing the teams based on *approved*. There are probably better ways to handle this but I think it's a fair approach.

Comment: TypeError: result.remove is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```js
Room.updateOne({ roomId: req.params.roomId}, {"$pull": { "teams": { approved: false } } })
```

This might work for your case.