# Mongoose: Property 'pull' does not exist on type 'Address[]'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm experiencing difficulties with Mongoose 5.10.0

Consider the following classes

Account:

```
export class Account {
    _id: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    phone: string;
    address?: Address[] = [];
}
```

Address:

```
export class Address {
    _id: string;
    streetName: string;
    zipCode: string;
    city: string;
    default: boolean | undefined;
}
```

And the appropriate DB models

Account:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from "mongoose";
import { Account } from "../classes/account.class";
import { addressSchema } from "./address.model";

export const accountSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    email: String,
    phone: String,
    password: String,
    address: [addressSchema],
);

export type AccountModel = Document & Account;
export const Accounts = mongoose.model<AccountModel>("Account", accountSchema);
```

Address:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from "mongoose";
import { Address } from "../classes/address.class";

export const addressSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    streetName: String,
    zipCode: String,
    city: String,
    default: Boolean,
});

export type AddressModel = Document & Address;
export const Addresses = mongoose.model<AddressModel>("Address", addressSchema);
```

Now when I get an account from the DB and try perform a pull against the address of the result, the `pull()` - method is not found at all and I get `Property 'pull' does not exist on type 'Address[]'.`

[image: Pull not found]

Is there something fundamentally wrong in the way the schema's are defined? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `Account[]` is an array. Arrays don't have a `pull` method.

Comment: Since there's an await in front of your statement I guess you want to run `pull` on the database side and you're looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56664906/remove-a-specific-nested-object-from-an-array-of-objects/56664983#56664983

Comment: @mickl Thanks for pushing me to the right way, that solved the issue. Care to make it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you're expecting MongoDB's `pull` operator to be a JavaScript method. You have two ways to achieve what you're trying to do:

You can either use `.findOne()` to retrieve the document, use JS code to modify the array (e.g. `slice`) and then run `.save()` to synchronize these changes with your db.

However if pulling an address is all you want to do then you can run an update operation directly on the database:

```
await Accounts.update({_id: idToFind}, {"$pull": { "address": { _id: addressId } } })
```

You'll end up having only one database call when using this 2nd approach

Answer (score 1):

according to @ZefirTheFear suggestion I tried somethings and it worked for me.

Actually I am using Nestjs. In my entity file I changed only one line:
It was like that.

```
  @Prop({type: [UserAnimalsSchema]})
  @Type(()=>UserAnimals)
  userAnimals: UserAnimals[]
```

I changed it like that :

```
  @Prop({type: [UserAnimalsSchema]})
  @Type(()=>Types.DocumentArray<UserAnimals>)
  userAnimals: Types.DocumentArray<UserAnimals>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Types } from "mongoose";
import { AddressModel } from './Address';

const account = await Accounts.findOne({_id: idToFind});
const accountAddressArray = account.address as Types.DocumentArray<AddressModel>
accountAddress.pull(...)
```

Comment: what is the goal here? please have some text describing your code, just putting code block without intro or comments is generally unhelpful.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, the goal (suddenly) is to resolve the issue of the author

Comment: This answer worked for me even though the author didn't give any context. Thanks to mongoose I should be able to use account.address.pull but Typescript didn't like it. I could of course use vanilla JS to remove the element from the array but the mongoose method is quite handy.